pygame timer not counting down linear or lagging badly
I'm making a simple word search style game and trying to get a timer but the timer is decreasing too quickly before it settles.
TIMER_EVENT = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(TIMER_EVENT, 1000)
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == TIMER_EVENT: 
            time_limit -= 1
            draw_grid(grid_size)  # Update the grid to show the updated timer
            pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.delay(100)`

this is my current code. I tried adding in a delay which did nothing. When I have run the program the increments are constantly changing times. I have also tried the pygame timer function which had a massive delay at the start before going down properly which also cannot happen.

@Noel I have tried that code but it still meant a big lag at the start and then decreasing sporadically

Please [edit] your question to show a [mre], it's not clear why you'd get the behaviour you describe. Does your draw_grid function includes slow code, e.g., loading images from disk? If so, that could be delaying initial execution so that multiple timer events are queued and then handled without your expected delay. Your event handlers should generally do little and execute fast. A typical game loop clears and draws the entire screen every iteration.

You should never call pygame.time.delay(100).
Exmaple: Imagine you're currently in the frame before the USEREVENT is added to the queue, and then pygame.time.delay(100) is called. Your game stops for 100ms. Now you have a ~100ms second lag.
Imagine you're in the frame ~20ms before the event should be added, and then pygame.time.delay(100) is called. Your game stops for 100ms. Now you have a ~80ms second lag, etc. etc.
Never do this.
Use a pygame.time.Clock to limit the framerate. It's not the best, but the easiest way that works.
Some other things:
For your custom event, you can use pygame.event.custom_type.
Never call pygame.display.flip() more than once per frame. Call it once at the end of your main loop, and above all not in an event loop if you don't know what you're doing.

okay thank you, i changed it to use the clock and it seems to be working better. apologies for my sloppy code i am quite new to coding but i really appreciate your advice
